# OOP exercise involving Animal subclasses

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented

I have implemented the following logic: a base class, `Animal`, has a vector, `friends`. A derived class, `Dog`, then inherits from `Animal`.

I then want to implement a `set_friends()` function that can be passed a `Dog` object and then fill its friends vector. I then want to be able to call `print_friends()` from the base class to print out the friends that were set in `set_friends()`.

When executed it produces the desired effect. However, I am curious if people know of any cleaner way to achieve the same end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Animal{
    private:
        int height;
        int weight;
        string name;

    public:
        int getHeight(){ return height; }
        int getWeight(){ return weight; }
        string getName(){ return name; }
        vector<Animal> *friends;
        void print_friends() {
            for(Animal a : *friends) {
                cout << a.getName() << endl;
            }
        }; 
        Animal(int height, int weight, string name) :
        height(height), weight(weight), name(name) {};

};

class Dog : public Animal {

    private:
        string sound = "woof";
    public:
        void getSound() { cout << sound << endl; }
        Dog(int h, int w, string n): Animal(h, w, n) {};
};

void set_friends(Dog& d) {
    Animal b(1, 2, "bb");
    vector<Animal> d_friends;
    d_friends.push_back(b);
    d.friends = &d_friends;
}
int main()
{
    Dog d(1, 2, "doggy");
    set_friends(d);
    d.print_friends();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Being this C++, you create the instance of Animal a inside set_friends, and once you exit this function the instance of animal is destroyed. Once you call print_friends you get an access violation because the memory of animal a has been freed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are some things to be improved.

1. Do *not* use namespace::std; Google it or just drop it.
2. Add all the necessary headers. You are missing string `#include <string>`
3. If you have to implement getter functions declare them const.

   ```
   int getHeight() const { return height; }
   ```
4. I dont really get why your animal class has no sound member but your dog does.
5. As @fernando.reyes said, your setFriends method is buggy. this should be a member function of you animal class that takes a animal and adds it to the friends. If friends are bidirectional you can add a wrapper that takes two animals

   ```
   void makeFriends(Animal& oneFriend, Animal& otherFriend) {
       oneFriend.addFriend(otherFriend);      
       otherFriend.addFriend(oneFriend);
   }

   void Animal::addFriend(const Animal& newFriend) {
       friends.push_back(&newFriend);
   }

   Dog d1(1, 2, "doggy");
   Dog d2(1, 2, "lassy");
   makeFriends(d1, d2);
   ```
6. I think your friends vector is wrong. You should have `std::vector<Animal*>` rather than `std::vector<Animal> *`. Otherwise you get problems with ownership.
7. I would suggest to use auto &elem for range based loops. In any case you should at least use `Animal* a : friends` rather than passing by copy

   ```
   void print_friends() {
       for(auto &animal : friends) {
           std::cout << animal->getName() << endl;
       }
   };
   ```

Comment: If the getName() call is const-ified, you can do auto const& also.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. On your point number 3, could you please explain or link me to a reference that explains the use of const in that position? I Understand the use of const in the position before or immediately after the type of a variable but I do not know of its significance in the position after the name

Comment: @LukePurnell The const before the function body indicates, that this function cannot alter the objects state. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration